# how to create custom object/array using twilio fetch conference function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, twilio

I have been trying to generate custom object array or JSON object to fetch specific fields of conferences object that Twilio fetch conference API provides. But since Node.js is async so unable to achieve that and gets undefined in return as their is call back in each function. Tried various approaches but unable to get the result as due to operation nature of node.js call back is registered and next statement is executed. Tried various options of promises and async-await as well. However, unable to achieve a result which might be a call back within each loop (my guess).

Since new to Node.Js so need some suggestion how to achieve. One option is to use settimeout but again this is not a genuine solution as in case of a system in production unable to get information on how much time required. Code is given below:

```
exports.fetchLiveConferences = function(req, res, next) {
    let conferencesArray = [];

    client.conferences.each({
        dateCreated: new Date(),
        status: 'In-progress'
    }, conferences => {
        /* call back function at this point conferences object is available and can extract properties so pushing it to my array.
         */
        conferencesArray.push({
            conferenceSid: conferences.sid,
            conferenceName: conferences.friendlyName,
            conferenceStatus: conferences.status,
        });
    })

    console.log(conferencesArray);
    /* due to async nature the below statement is executed once call back is registered by node.js in event loop and undefined is returned. 
     */
    res.send(conferencesArray);
}
```

Comment: What type of object is `client.conferences` and is there documentation for it?

Comment: This object pertains to Twilio Voice SDK. For reference please follow following link https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference?code-sample=code-read-list-an-in-progress-conference&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x

Comment: The `.each` function seems to be completely undocumented (or hidden very well). Normally one would map asynch tasks to promises and use `Promise.all` to see when it's done and if it failed instead of tying together a bunch of callbacks and console logging errors (that's not really handling an error)

Comment: Yeah tried all approaches and then posted the question as async await or promise.all functionalists within .each function does not provide the desired results. Documentation needs a little revision so hope that same would be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for responses, specially Phil for mentioning list approach with map function. However, using twilio .each() method I was able to generate the custom object with following code.

```
exports.fetchLiveConferences = async function fetchLiveConferences(req, res, next){
const conferenceData = await fetchConferenceList();
res.send(conferenceData);
}

fetchConferenceList = function () {
let conferenceArray = [];
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.conferences.each({
            dateCreated: new Date(),
            status: 'in-progress'
        },
        conferences => {
            conferenceArray.push({
                conferenceSid: conferences.sid,
                conferenceName: conferences.friendlyName,
                conferenceStatus: conferences.status
            });
            resolve(conferenceArray);
        })
})
}
```

Comment: Using `each` and then building up an array with the results is effectively doing the same as using `list`. But now it's complicated by throwing a `Promise` instantiation in. If you are looking to use Promises/async/await the `list` method actually returns a promise too. Check out the update to my answer for a promise based way of doing this that doesn't require that.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your issue here is that you are using `each` to list the conferences independently. If you just want to work with the list, then you should use the `list` method and then return the results in the callback.

Try something like this.

```
exports.fetchLiveConferences = function(req, res, next) {
  client.conferences.list({
      dateCreated: new Date(),
      status: 'In-progress'
  }, (err, conferences) => {
    if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
    conferencesArray = conferences.map(conference => ({
        conferenceSid: conference.sid,
        conferenceName: conference.friendlyName,
        conferenceStatus: conference.status,
    }));
    res.send(conferencesArray);
  })
}
```

In this case the `conferences` onject in the callback is a list of conferences. You can then `map` over the conferences and build the objects that you want, returning them as the response.

**Update**

If you want to uses promises and `async` and `await` the `list` method also returns a promise. You can use it like this.

```
const fetchConferenceList = () => {
  return client.conferences.list({
    dateCreated: new Date(),
    status: 'In-progress'
  }).then(conferences => conferences.map(conference => ({
    conferenceSid: conference.sid,
    conferenceName: conference.friendlyName,
    conferenceStatus: conference.status,
  })));
}

exports.fetchLiveConferences = async function(req, res, next) {
  const conferenceData = await fetchConferenceList();
  res.send(conferenceData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. However, getting following error.                        conferencesArray = conferences.map(conference => ({
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null. Used console log and seems and conferences is returning null

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I tend to use the promise form which gets the object as the first argument. In the callback form like you have here, there is an error object first (which is `null` when the request was a success). I've updated my code in the answer to handle the error.

Comment: Thanks for swift response, still a minor adjustment required in code as array is returned however, with undefined properties. Need to use conference instead of conferences to resolve.                                   conferencesArray = conferences.map(conference => ({
          conferenceSid: conference.sid,
          conferenceName: conference.friendlyName,
          conferenceStatus: conference.status,
      })

Comment: Bah, that's what I get for not running my code . I've updated the answer again. Hope you're all sorted with this now

Comment: Ah, that's the constant fun of programming one enjoy even after many and many years of development. Code seems fine now. Thanks for great help.

Comment: Ah yes, it never gets old! Glad you’re sorted, good luck with the rest of the app.

Comment: The answer given above worked but I still explored the .each function of twilio and got the answer. In my answer used Async await approach with promise combination. Need advise of Phil whether, it's better approach or his list method with use of map is better one.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to put your `res.send` function inside the callback like such:

```
client.conferences.each({
    dateCreated: new Date(),
    status: 'In-progress'
}, conferences => {
    /* call back function at this point conferences object is available and can extract properties so pushing it to my array.
     */
    conferencesArray = conferences.map(c => {
        return {
            conferenceSid: c.sid,
            conferenceName: c.friendlyName,
            conferenceStatus: c.status,
        }
    });
    res.send(conferencesArray);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Used the above code however, unable to receive the output. Replaced console.log with res.send however, no output received. Waiting for response. Also added console.log on your code where comments are given in the above code i.e. first statement of call back function again no out.